# When using the Template variant rule from Xanathar's Guide to Everything, do 5 foot wide Lines actually affect a 10 foot wide row of grid squares?

Tags: dnd-5e, area-of-effect, battle-map

Xanathar's Guide to Everything has a few variant options for playing on a Grid.

XGtE, Page 86:

> ... Choose an intersection of squares as the point of origin of an area of effect ...
>
> ... If any part of a square is under the template, that square is included in the area of effect. ...

Diagrams 2.1 & 2.2 show this, with the Cone's origin being on the intersection. Its shadow clearly covers small sections of both squares just after the intersection.

PHB, Page 205:

> A line extends from its point of origin in a straight path up to its length and covers an area defined by its width.

My interpretation is that this means using templates on grids increases the average Area of Effect size notably for Cones & Lines particularly.

Does that seem correct?

Visual example:
[image]

Which would affect all 4 enemies labeled 1 if the caster is the one labeled 2.

Comment: Related, though none are duplicates: "[The Gust of Wind spell creates a 10-foot-wide line of wind originating from the caster; how do I center it on a 5-foot grid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177078)" and "[What space does the spell Cloud of Daggers fill?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128445)" and "[What is the area affected by Gust of Wind on a grid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100114)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using a battlemap, can a lightning bolt be directed between squares to affect both?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119327/when-using-a-battlemap-can-a-lightning-bolt-be-directed-between-squares-to-affe)

Comment: I would say that directly answers the asked question. Thanks. @samuei